# Remove list item from unordered list with chrome extension

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm really new to this. I'm making an extension for chrome to remove elements from a list depending on a condition. Each item in list has a div tag and div tag has either following class or not_following class. example

```
<div title="UnFollow" class="following" ... </div>
```

or

```
<div title="Follow" class="not_following" ... </div>
```

I want to remove the item if it has following class. here the code I have so far it works for first item.

```
var element = document.querySelector("list > li:nth-child(1)");
if(document.querySelector("list > li:nth-child(1) > div.following")){
  element.remove();
}
```

how do I make a loop so it works for every item in the list.

Comment: for (const el of document.querySelector('.following')) { el.remove(); }

Comment: I get this error  Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Comment: It should be querySelectorAll, sorry.

Comment: it works but i'm trying to remove parent element of that class which is <li>

Comment: Then el.closest('li').remove();

Comment: thanks for your help. works perfectly fine.